# How to access list in SharePoint Hosted App?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, 2013

I want to create an Sharepoint hosted app but how to access list in these App ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample code of JavaScript Client Object Model to perform action you want.

```
  var context;
    var hostweburl;
    var appweburl;
    var appContextSite;
    var list;
    var web;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getUrl);
    });

    function getUrl () { 
        hostweburl = getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl");
        appweburl = getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl");
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(hostweburl);
        appweburl = decodeURIComponent(appweburl);
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";  
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
                    function () {
                        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",
                        function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execOperation); }
                        );
                    }
                );
            event.preventDefault(); 
    }

    function execOperation() {
        context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
        var factory =
            new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(
                appweburl
            );
        context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
        appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);
        web = appContextSite.get_web();
        context.load(web);
        list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("User Detail");
        context.load(list);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
        }
        function onSuccess() {
              alert("List loaded Successfully");    
        }

        // This function is executed if the above call fails
        function onFail(sender, args) {
               alert( args.get_message());
        }
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
                var params =
                    document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
                    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
                    if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve)
                        return singleParam[1];
                }
            }
```

Comment: its giving error..

Comment: @Torque I think the executeQueryAsync statement and the success and callback functions are missing from your code.

Comment: Can you please tell me which error??

Comment: @RajeshJoshi please check the code again. I have updated the code.

Comment: its giving error at hostweburl = getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl");

Comment: When you run your app Check the URL for..
1) SpHostURL
2) SpAppWebURL

Comment: @Torque you have not included the `getQueryStringParameter` and `decodeURIComponent` functions in your code.

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande Thanx mate, I forgot to add them..

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: 'getQueryStringParameter' is undefined

Comment: @RajeshJoshi I forgot to add that Code. 
please check the code again.. I have added that function at end of code.

Comment: @Torque this line ( context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);) doesn't execute, giving error of access denied

Comment: @RajeshJoshi check this link.. It shows how to resolve error you which is coming to you.
http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2012/11/sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-hosted-app-permissions/

Comment: @Torque still getting error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7005/discussion-between-torque-and-rajesh-joshi)

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2013 when you create any SharePoint Hosted App it will create separate web for the app you created so when you will open your app check the URL there will be

1) SPHostUrl
2) SPAppWebUrl

If you want to access List from SpHostWeb you will have to use Cross Domain Concept to access it.

Follow this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927%28v=office.15%29.aspx) Link it shows how to access List in SharePoint hosted app.

Comment: SharePoint Hosted App doesn't create separate web

Comment: Do one thing. Open your App which you have created and then check this Link below..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179925.aspx

Comment: Problem with your MSDN link, is that it assumes you are packaging the List with your (Client)WebApp.  Here is my problem: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94059/cross-domain-access-limited-or-not-happening

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to use the SP.AppContextSite" instead of default "SP.ClientContext" to get the SharePoint site URL.

SP.AppContextSite used to get the host site URL and SP.ClientContext used to get the app web URL.

Please refer my below link on how to access the list:
http://sharepointquicksolutions.blogspot.in/2013/01/is-list-exists-or-not-using-ecmascript.html

Please reach out me for any issue or additional information required.

-Thanks,
Sasi Kumar Reddy
http://sharepointquicksolutions.blogspot.in