# SharePoint Apps - Where does my Custom List get created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

When we add a custom list into a SharePoint apps in VS, where does it get created? will it be created on the app site or on the SharePoint site(which consumes the app)?

**Edit**
how to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be created in the App Web. You can access it by using Client Object Model, see here for a very similar question: [How to access list in SharePoint Hosted App?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55334/how-to-access-list-in-sharepoint-hosted-app)