# Cross-Domain access limited or not happening

Tags: 2013, external-content-type, csom

I am having issues connecting to the Host Site of the App, to query a List and obtain information.

If i manually navigate to the url,  `HostURL/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('tblTestList')/items?$select=BdcIdentity,value', it executes and produces and expected XML result.

But when i execute a similar query using Ajax/Json, i get either Cross-Domain error response or the Log below, which results in short to Cross-Domain.

In both situations they are at least in the same SiteCollection.  Both are being hosted under the same account under O365.  Eventually i will be moving this to our internal SharePoint but i need to see what i can, or can not, do because clients of ours will be using this and other controls through extranet portal.

Please look at the below and let me know what you think.  Whether i use the JS/Ajax API URL syntax or the JSOM syntax, i get the same result.

I just need one or the other to work.  Any help would be greatful.

And if it matters the List is actually an ECT with a BCS connection.  I dont need to Push/Put to the List, just need to Get from it.

### AppManifest.xml:

```
<App xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest"
     Name="SQLTextBox"
     ProductID="{158edc40-7ce4-4c5e-a7ab-2e72b3179b3b}"
     Version="1.0.0.0"
     SharePointMinVersion="15.0.0.0"
>
    <Properties>
        <Title>SQLTextBox</Title>
        <StartPage>~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
    </Properties>

    <AppPrincipal>
        <Internal AllowedRemoteHostUrl="~remoteAppUrl" />
    </AppPrincipal>
  <AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="false">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/bcs/connection" Right="Read" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Read" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
</App>
```

### Default/WebApp Pages:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming" runat="server" />

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';

        // Set the style of the client web part page to be consistent with the host web.
        (function () {
            var hostUrl = '';
            if (document.URL.indexOf('?') != -1) {
                var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var p = decodeURIComponent(params[i]);
                    if (/^SPHostUrl=/i.test(p)) {
                        hostUrl = p.split('=')[1];
                        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + hostUrl + '/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx" />');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hostUrl == '') {
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/themable/corev15.css" />');
            }
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label id="lblWelcome">
            <!-- The following content will be replaced with the user name when you run the app - see App.js -->
            initializing...
        </label>
        <label id="sqlData">Loading Data...</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### App.js

```
'use strict';

var qsParams = {}, qsHostUrl, qsAppUrl, factory, lstData;
var currContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = currContext.get_web();
var user = web.get_currentUser();

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a currContext object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
$(document).ready(function () {
    parseQueryString();
    assignQueryStringVariables();

    getUserName();

    $.getScript(qsHostUrl + "/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);
});
// Function to prepare and issue the request to get
//  SharePoint data
function execCrossDomainRequest() {
    currContext = new SP.ClientContext(qsAppUrl);
    factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(qsAppUrl);
    currContext.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(currContext, qsHostUrl);

    this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
    currContext.load(this.web);

    var lst = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('tblTestList');
    var caml = "<View><ViewFields" +
        "<FieldRef Name='BdcIdentity' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='value' />" +
        "</ViewFields></View>";

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(caml);

    lstData = lst.getItems(camlQuery);
    currContext.load(lstData, "Include(BdcIdentity,value)");

    currContext.executeQueryAsync(postData, postError);

    function postData(data, req) {
        var outHtml = "";
        var iter = lstData.getEnumerator();

        outhtml = "<H2>tblTestList Data</H2><table>";
        while (iter.moveNext()) {
            var itm = iter.get_current();
            outhtml = outhtml +
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + itm.get_item("BdcIdentity") + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + itm.get_item("value") + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
        }

        outhtml = outhtml + "</table>";

        $("sqlData").html(outhtml);
    }

    function postError(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        $("#sqlData").html("<span>Could not complete cross-domain call: " + errorCode + " - " + errorMessage + "</span>");
    }
}

// Parse the Query string from the URL
function parseQueryString() {
    var temp, i, l; //unassigned declarations

    //assignment declarations
    var url = document.URL;
    var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1);
    var params = qs.split("&");

    for (i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
        temp = params[i].split('=');
        qsParams[temp[0]] = temp[1];
    }
}

function assignQueryStringVariables() {
    qsAppUrl = decodeURIComponent(qsParams["SPAppWebUrl"]);
    qsHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(qsParams["SPHostUrl"]);
}

// This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the current users information
function getUserName() {
    currContext.load(user);
    currContext.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
}

// This function is executed if the above call is successful
// It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
    $('#lblWelcome').text('Hello ' + user.get_title());
}

// This function is executed if the above call fails
function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

### Chrome Developer Log:

```
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:26 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):The frame element does not exist. Put request in queue SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:26 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):Created IFrame https://appdomain/SQLTextBox/_layouts/15…appdomain/SQLTextBox/Pages/Default.aspx SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:26 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):Create IFrameLoadTimeout 11 SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/css: "https://appdomain/_layouts/15/1033/styles/corev15app.css?rev=sXnpy4muBCj0VRzQDI3uMg%3D%3D". init.js?rev=VzO%2FY8hYnnXmC5pJBAUtHQ%3D%3D:1
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.Init sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.addEventListener sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):Processing IFRAME onload event SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):Clear IFrameLoadTimeout 11 SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):Start to ping the IFRAME https://appdomain/SQLTextBox/_layouts/15/AppWebProxy.aspx SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):Create IFramePingTimeout 49 SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.PostMessage.Message: {"command":"Ping","postMessageId":"SP.RequestExecutor2"} SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.PostMessage.Target: https://appdomain/SQLTextBox/_layouts/15/AppWebProxy.aspx SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.OnMessage sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.OnMessage: Message.data={"command":"Ping","postMessageId":"SP.RequestExecutor2"} sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.OnMessage: Message.origin=https://appdomain sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.OnMessage: Processing ping command sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.PostMessage.Message: {"command":"Ping","postMessageId":"SP.RequestExecutor2","responseAvailable":false,"errorCode":0,"errorMessage":""} sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.PostMessage.Target: https://appdomain sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.OnMessage SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.OnMessage: Message.data={"command":"Ping","postMessageId":"SP.RequestExecutor2","responseAvailable":false,"errorCode":0,"errorMessage":""} SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.OnMessage: Message.origin=https://appdomain SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):Successfully load frame for https://appdomain/SQLTextBox/_layouts/15/AppWebProxy.aspx SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.PostMessage.Message: {"command":"Query","url":"https://appdomain/SQLTextBox/_api/contextinfo","method":"POST","body":null,"headers":{"ACCEPT":"application/json;odata=verbose"},"postMessageId":"SP.RequestExecutor1","timeout":180000} SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.PostMessage.Target: https://appdomain/SQLTextBox/_layouts/15/AppWebProxy.aspx SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.OnMessage sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.OnMessage: Message.data={"command":"Query","url":"https://appdomain/SQLTextBox/_api/contextinfo","method":"POST","body":null,"headers":{"ACCEPT":"application/json;odata=verbose"},"postMessageId":"SP.RequestExecutor1","timeout":180000} sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.OnMessage: Message.origin=https://appdomain sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.PostMessage.Message: {"command":"Query","postMessageId":"SP.RequestExecutor1","responseAvailable":false,"errorCode":-1004,"errorMessage":"Your appdomain doesn't match the expected appdomain for this app deployment."} sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutorMessageProcessor.PostMessage.Target: https://appdomain sp.requestexecutor.js?rev=rvModk43dz0x3w5dN4u%2BBA%3D%3D:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.OnMessage SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.OnMessage: Message.data={"command":"Query","postMessageId":"SP.RequestExecutor1","responseAvailable":false,"errorCode":-1004,"errorMessage":"Your appdomain doesn't match the expected appdomain for this app deployment."} SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
Mon Mar 24 2014 15:48:27 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time):RequestExecutor.OnMessage: Message.origin=https://appdomain SP.RequestExecutor.js?_=1395693884243:2
```

Comment: Got a solution to get the Host sites Title & Description to show up, now going to try and access the List and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, did you find solution for "The frame element does not exist. Put request in queue"? This issue occurs in IE only in my case.

Comment: No, basically if you have an On-Premise environment you don't use App-Parts.  Especially if you have a mixed render environment (Internet, Intranet, Extranet, etc) and need to use content across all of them using the App Part.